# Fortran code runs but doesn't display any input

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, gfortran

Hi I am using Visual Studio code to try to run some fortran code. I have two issues. Firstly, I am able to run the program in the command line using the fortran compiler I have installed (I know it runs as when there is an error it flags it in the command line). However, the issue is that when I put code with no error it runs, however doesn't display the input I expect. This is the code, which I copied from a youtube tutorial.

```
program Test
    implicit none
    character*20 :: name
    print *, "Name:"
    read *, name
    print *, name
end program Test
```

When it is run, the command line command runs and doesn't present an error, but nothing is output, just a new line. Any ideas on what is causing this.

Also I would like to run it directly from Visual Studio Code, however I am unable to link the compiler to VSC. I have done it before with Python code, and when I press `F5` it will run, however when I do the same with the fortran file, it just gives a menu:
[image: Menu]
I have installed the `Modern Fortran` extension for VSC. Any idea on what is happening?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say "I am able to run the program in the command line using the fortran compiler", how are you doing this? What compiler, and what compile and run commands?

Comment: @veryreverie I'm using the compiler from MinGW. And all I put was `gfortran.exe "[file path]"`

Comment: `gfortran.exe [file]` will compile the file. Are you then running it?

Comment: @veryreverie Ah ok, I see what you mean now. I can run the file just like an .exe by clicking on it, but how is there a way to run it in VSC?

Comment: @veryreverie Also, when I run it, rather than just running from the .f90 file it produces a file `a.exe` in the same directory, which runs as the program should. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes, this is normal. Fortran is a compiled language, so you have to compile the source into a program and then run the program. See e.g. [this tutorial](https://fortran-lang.org/learn/building_programs/compiling_source). I'm afraid I can't help you with VSC as I've never used it. Hopefully someone else will come along who has :)

Comment: @veryreverie Ok, thank you very much for your help